# How to use UPDATE SET without making other column values NULL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having this issue where no matter how I use UPDATE SET the result always deletes or NULL the other values.

How do I ONLY perform UPDATE SET to change only specific values?
Is this easier with INSERT INTO?

This is what the table looks like before any changes.

Intention: I want to ONLY add values to -> pe_DeathAncestoryFinal_testpilotdeathtime

WHERE -> pe_DeathAncestoryFinal_pilotdeathcount = 0

[image: Before image]

//If no deaths (pe_DeathAncestoryFinal_pilotdeathcount = 0) then record first reported time as last death.

```
   $sql = 'UPDATE pe_DeathAncestoryFinal 
    SET pe_DeathAncestoryFinal_lastpilotdeathtime = (
    SELECT CASE WHEN(pe_DeathAncestoryFinal_pilotdeathcount = 0) THEN pe_LogEvent_datetime END
    FROM pe_LogEvent 
    WHERE pe_DeathAncestoryFinal_pilotdeathcount = 0 AND pe_LogEvent_id = 1
    GROUP BY pe_DeathAncestoryFinal_pilotname
   )';
```

This is the table after I run my code.

You can see that it deleted/NULL all the other values and then added the values where pilotdeathcount = 0.
[image: After Image]

This is NOT what I want, I only intend on updating 3 rows WHERE -> pe_DeathAncestoryFinal_pilotdeathcount = 0

Comment: CLICK ON THEM AND THEY ARE CLEAR!

Comment: Sorry, that's one of automatic comments that's is posted during posts/questions review. Here is one of a reasons why someone flag or close your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: I'm not the one who downvote your question (it got downvoted twice), also I'm not the author of the article I've sent you above, but I totally agree with it. Sometimes I'm using stackexchange on my mobile and this is how I see images from your post (after resize): https://imgur.com/gallery/xYgNW6D, it's hardly readable on my 2560x1440 resolution monitor, not talking about phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May i ask what is the values and structure in your [pe_LogEvent] table?

In the meantime, try this.

Correct me if im wrong.

Thank you

```
UPDATE [your_table_name] SET pe_DeathAncestoryFinal_pilotdeathcount = 
(SELECT pe_LogEvent_datetime FROM pe_LogEvent WHERE pe_LogEvent_id = 1) 
WHERE pe_DeathAncestoryFinal_pilotdeathcount = 0
```